# Embed matplotlib in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

I try to embed matplotlib into PyQT GUI made in Qt designer. In .ui on a  widget tab I defined:
GraphWidget, that is a QWidget
and
Graph1Layout, that is a QVBoxLayout.

The code is below. I took some parts of the code from other application written by other person (class ParentCanvas and class PlotCanvas) so I do not completely understand what is going on there, but as far as I googled, that is the almost standard way to include matplotlib widget in GUI. I shortened my existing code and existing GUI to do a little example.

What is intended: I want to plot some points whenever I click run and delete the graph when I click stop (I tried just to clear the points from graph but without success).

Is this correct implementation?
Maybe somebody can make it more simple or better?
Is there a better way to delete widget?
How to delete only points on the plot?

I am a beginner in OOP and python in general. Any other comments for improving the code are welcome.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys,os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic  # Used to create and modify PyQt4 Objects.
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas    # Used in creating the plots and graphs.
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class ParentCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        fig.set_edgecolor('w')
        fig.set_facecolor('w')
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.hold(False)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class PlotCanvas(ParentCanvas):
    """ Creates a matplotlib canvas QWidget inheriting the features set out in ParentCanvas."""
    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.set_xbound(lower=0, upper=1)
        self.axes.set_ybound(lower=0, upper=1)
        self.axes.set_ylabel('Best Fitness Function')
        self.axes.set_xlabel('Population')


class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('Test.ui', self)
        self.SignalsAndSlots()
        self.firstrun = True
        self.iter=0


    def SignalsAndSlots(self):  # Function setting up the signals and slots.

        self.btnStopOpt.clicked.connect(self.clickStop)
        self.btnRun.clicked.connect(self.clickRun)


    def clickStop(self):  # Function that runs when the "Stop" button is clicked.

        self.firstrun = True
        self.iter =0
        self.gb.setParent(None)

    def clickRun(self):  # Function that runs when the "Run Optimization" button is clicked.

        if self.firstrun == True :
            #graph setup
            self.gb = PlotCanvas(self.Graph1Widget, width=10, height=7, dpi=70)
            self.gb.axes.set_ylabel('Objective Value')
            self.gb.axes.set_xlabel('Generation')
            self.Graph1Layout.addWidget(self.gb)
            self.firstrun = False

        self.UpdateGraph(self.iter)

        self.iter+=1

    def UpdateGraph(self, iter):    # Function that creates a graph

        best = [0,0,0,3,5,9,12,30]
        average = [0,0,0,1,2,3,14,20]

        t = range(iter+1)    # Will be used to store the generation numbers.
        s = best[:iter+1]    # Will be used to store the global best values.

        self.gb.axes.hold(True)    # Holds the graph so we can plot the global best and average scores as two separate scatter plots on to one graph.

        self.gb.axes.scatter(t, s, c='b', label='Best objective value')

        if iter == 0:    # In the first generation we need to make a legend for the graph, this only need to be made once.
            self.gb.axes.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.09), fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)    # Legend content is determined by the labels above. Location is determined by bbox_to_anchor.

        self.gb.axes.autoscale_view(True,False,True)

        self.gb.draw()

        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main(None)  # instantiation
    app.setActiveWindow(window)
    window.show()  # show window
    sys.exit(app.exec_())  # Exit from Python
```

Comment: I feel like there's a good question in here somewhere, but it's a bit too rambling - what is actually the problem?  Does this code work like you expect or not?  It's impossible for us to run it because we don't have your 'Test.ui'.